# HibernateJpaConfiguration java.lang.NullPointerException when I use 2 ManyToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following tables:

- user

[image]

- role

[image]

- room

[image]

`user` + `role` and `user` + `rooms` should be mapped by `@ManyToMany` table.

When I create the `user` & `role` entities all worked well,

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    //.........

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
            )
    private Set<UserRole> roles;
```

**UserRoles**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class UserRole extends AutoIncrementIdBaseEntity {

//....

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;
```

---

### > but when I try to add binding with `room` entity:

**User**

```
@ManyToMany 
@JoinTable(name = "user_room",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "room_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
)
private Set<Room> rooms;
```

**Room**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
public class Room extends BaseEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                            name = "uuid_gen_strategy_class",
                            value = "org.hibernate.id.uuid.CustomVersionOneStrategy"
                    )
            }
    )
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "rooms")
    private Set<User> userList;
```

I have the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I am already trying to use `LAZY`, `EAGER` methods, `@Proxy(lazy = false)`, and many others. But nothing not to help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Check my answer [on ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/993198/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-onetomany-onetoone-manytomany-manytoone-hibernate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem that I see is that you have not set the `mappedBy=` attributes correctly. The value should be the name of the field in the `owning` entity, e.g., `rooms` instead of `room`.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "rooms")
private Set<User> userList;
```

Also, don't use `FetchType.EAGER` without a specific use case and I don't know what that use case is. It will only lead to headaches. You should create specific queries to fetch relations when they are needed.

When your `Room` table has the foreign key of `creator_id` then you have a `OneToMany` relationship not a `ManyToMany` relationship. `ManyToMany` relationships must use a join table to be realized. A FK can only realize a `OneToMany` relationship. Here you must also set the `mappedBy` annotation properly.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="creator")
private Set<Room> rooms;
```

and

```
@ManyToOne
private User creator;
```

The `mappedBy` annotation specifies the owning entity.

> The field that owns the relationship. Required unless the relationship is unidirectional.

You have used `bidirectional` mappings throughout so you are using `mappedBy` annotations. The meaning of owning entity is the entity that is responsible for persisting the relation. In your example `Room` is responsible for persisting the `creator` relation and `User` is responsible for persisting the `user_role` relation. The final result could be

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
            )
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="creator")
    private Set<Room> rooms;

@Entity
public class Role { 

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;

@Entity
public class Room {

    @ManyToOne
    private User creator;
```

and a simple example of using it through `spring-data-jpa` could be

```
Role r1 = new Role();
roleRepo.save(r1);

User u1 = new User();
// needed to persist relation
u1.setRoles(Collections.singleton(r1));
// added to improve accuracy
r1.setUsers(Collections.singleton(u1));
userRepo.save(u1);

Room m1 = new Room();
// needed to persist relation
m1.setCreator(u1);
// added to improve accuracy
u1.setRooms(Collections.singleton(m1));
roomRepo.save(m1);
```

Note that you have to specifically manage both sides of a bidirectional relationship when using a specific instance without refreshing it:

> The Java Persistence API requires the references to be set on both sides of the relationship. This means that you have to explicitly call b.setA(a) and a.setB(b).

And so u1.setRooms(Collections.singleton(m1)); and r1.setUsers(Collections.singleton(u1)); is added so that the current user and role instances will have accurate rooms and users collections. If those instances will be reloaded from the database later with a new call to JPA, which is typical, then these would not be necessary.

Comment: Thank you!!
About `EAGER` type usage: when I do not use it I get something like "LazyInitializationError" (in each(!) project)

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi Check this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/)

Comment: True, the lazy init exception happens when attempting to access relations that have not been specifically fetched. You will need to learn how to specifically fetch the relations you want to access. I've seen good things with using @EntityGraph in repositories to handle this.